# Does sqoop import/export create java classes? If it does so, what is the location of these classes?

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, cglib

Does sqoop import/export create java classes? If it does so, where can I see these generated classes. What is the location of these class files?

Answer (score 5):

Does sqoop import/export create java classes?

> Yes

If it does so, where can I see these generated classes. What is the location of these class files?

> It automatically generates a java file of same table name in the
>   current path of local system.

You can use `--outdir` to provide your own path.

*Updated as per comment*

You can use codegen command for this:

```
 sqoop codegen \
--connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/databasename\
--username username\
--password password\
--table tablename
```

After the command is executed successfully there will be a path at the end where you can see the java files.

Comment: You forgot to mention the most important part, **`codegen`**

Answer (score 1):

This is the complete flow of sqoop commands

> User---> SQOOP CLI cmd ----> Sqoop Code GEN -----> Sqoop JAR Writer
>   ----> JAR submission ---> ResourceManager ----> MR operation (5phases) ----> HDFS ----> Ack to Sqoop by MR program

**

Sqoop internally uses MapReducev1 or v2 for its execution(Getting data from DB and Storing the same in HDFS in comma delimited values). And it first creates a .java source file  for the map-reduce prg and pakages in jar and then submits.
The .java is created in the current local directory with name of table.

```
sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoop --table employee -m 1
```

In this case a "employee.java" is created .